# TwoWayView vertical scrollbar within ScrollView

Tags: android

Twowayview vertical scrollbar isn't working with outer scrollview. how to make it right. need help!

```
    <ScrollView>
     ...

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
                <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/idSubCat"
                    style="@style/TwoWayView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
            </LinearLayout> 

   ...
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: add this line `setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)` where you are initiating TwoWayView .
Like twoWayView.setNestedScrollingEnable(true);

Comment: It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: nope! there's nothing to do with width, it's the height

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error once because TWV works fine with wrap_content only and i ended up with RecyclerView.